# Cannot find qml.ui file in visual studio

Tags: qt

I made a simple qt widget application using visual studio there were UI form files which I can open and edit UI in qt designer, now I want to shift to qml, I made a new qtquick application but I cannot find any qml.ui files.

Comment: Please share the existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What You are talking about is [QT Quick UI Form](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-ui-forms.html) which has the extension `ui.qml`. This `ui.qml` file is not "bundled" together with a new `Qt Quick Project`. You Can take a look for Yourself in the Qt Creator:

1. Go to: `File` -> `New File or Project`
2. Under the `Projects` section there is an option that You have probably chosen: `Application (Qt Quick)` which creates a **new application**
3. Under the `Files and Classes` section there is an option `Qt` and then You can **choose to create the file** You were looking for: QtQuick UI File:
   [image: Add QtQuick UI File]

As You can see, it says that it creates the form as a `ui.qml` file, that **You can later add to an *existing* Qt Quick Project**.

This is why You can't find the file with the form - You have to *create it* separately.